# Merging >2 files with AWK or JOIN?

Tags: join, awk

Merging 2 files using AWK is a well covered topic on StackOverflow. However, the technique of reading 3 files into an array gets more complicated. As I'm formatting the output to go into an R script, I'm going to need to add lots of syntax so I don't **think** I can use JOIN. Here is a simplistic version I have working so far:

```
awk 'FNR==1{f++}
     f==1{a[FNR]=$1;next}
     f==2{b[FNR]=$1;next}
     {print a[FNR], "<- c(", b[FNR], ",", $1, ")"}' words.txt x.txt y.txt
```

Where:

```
$ cat words.txt
word1
word2
word3

$ cat x.txt
1
2
3

$ cat y.txt
11
22
33
```

The output is then

```
word1 <- c(1, 11)
word2 <- c(2, 22)
word3 <- c(3, 22)
```

The best way I can summarize this technique is

1. Create a variable f to keep track of which file you're processing
2. For file 1 read the values into array a
3. For file 2 read the values into array b
4. Fall through to file three, where you concatenate your final output

As a beginner to AWK, this works, but I find it a bit awkward and I worry coming back to the code in 6 months, I'll no longer understand it. Is this the best way to merge these 3 files in AWK? Could JOIN actually handle this level of formatting the final output?

Comment: Could you please post sample output too in code tags and let us know?

Comment: I did:
word1 <- c(1, 11)
word2 <- c(2, 22)
word3 <- c(3, 22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a variation of @RavinderSingh13's solution

```
$ paste {words,x,y}.txt | awk '{print $1, "<- c(" $2 ", " $3 ")"}'
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit overwhelmed by the creativity and support on Stack Overflow. All three of these answers are helpful. What I like about this answer is that by using Paste, it can handle more files (as did @ravinderSingh's solution) but by having a simpler AWK solution, it keeps more of the readability I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Could you please try following.

```
paste words.txt x.txt y.txt | awk '{$2="<- c("$2", "$3")";$3="";sub(/ +$/,"")} 1'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
word1 <- c(1, 11)
word2 <- c(2, 22)
word3 <- c(3, 33)
```

---

---

In case you simply want to add 3 file's contents in column vice then try following.

```
paste words.txt x.txt y.txt 
word1   1   11
word2   2   22
word3   3   33
```

Comment: Thank you, but I explicitly wrote the question to make sure it was clear I needed the output to be in R script format. I need the output to be: 
word1 <- c(1, 11)
word2 <- c(2, 22)
word3 <- c(3, 22)

Your example doesn't do that

Comment: @ScottJenson, could you please check my EDIT solution and let me know?

Comment: Thank you, that clearly works and uses PASTE, which is obviously simpler at merging the files. However, it then requires a fairly complex AWK string to 'fix' the formatting. The solution from @Tiw using ARGIND feels easier to me as there is much more control creating the output.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for readability, you can change the file checking method, as well as the variable names.
Try these please:

```
awk 'ARGIND==1{words[FNR]=$1;}
     ARGIND==2{xcol[FNR]=$1;}
     ARGIND==3{print words[FNR], "<- c(", xcol[FNR], ",", $1, ")"}' words.txt x.txt y.txt
```

Above file checking method is for GNU awk.

Change to another, as well as change the file reading order, would be:

```
awk 'FILENAME=="words.txt"{print $1, "<- c(", xcol[FNR], ",", ycol[FNR], ")";}
     FILENAME=="x.txt"{xcol[FNR]=$1;}
     FILENAME=="y.txt"{ycol[FNR]=$1;}' x.txt y.txt words.txt
```

As you can also see here, file reading order and block order can be different.
Since `words.txt` has first column, or `main column`, so to speak, so it's sensible to read it last.

You can also use `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` `FILENAME==ARGV[2]` etc to check files, and put comments inside (use `awk` script file and load with `awk -f scriptfile` is better with comments):

```
awk 'FILENAME==ARGV[1]{xcol[FNR]=$1;} #Read column B, x column
     FILENAME==ARGV[2]{ycol[FNR]=$1;} # Read column C, y cloumn
     FILENAME==ARGV[3]{print $1, "<- c(", xcol[FNR], ",", ycol[FNR], ")";}' x.txt y.txt words.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! You 'got' my need for readability and your suggestions are all excellent. It also hints at how to add a 4th file (if necessary)

Comment: NOOB mistake, I didn't try your solution before replying. Alas, I'm on a Mac and not using GNU awk, ARGINT doesn't appear to be supported.  However, the FILENAME==ARGV[1] trick DOES work. It's verbose to be sure but it's clear. I'll follow your suggestion to use a script file input so it can be structured and commented which is far more important.

Comment: @ScottJenson Well, how about `brew install gawk` and start using `gawk` command ;)